# NHibernate new version upgrade

Tags: c#, nhibernate, version, webapi

I have upgraded from the NHibernate version from '3.3.1.4000' to '4.1.2.4000' in a C# based WebAPI project. The build and debugging was successful in my local machine.
After deploying in test server, I am getting the following error.

Could not load file or assembly 'NHibernate, Version=3.3.1.4000, Culture=neutral. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference

After deploying in test server, I am getting the following error.

Could not load file or assembly 'NHibernate, Version=3.3.1.4000,

Comment: do you have assembly redirects somewhere in you .config files?

Comment: Yes . I have assembly redirects in the config file.

Comment: Do those points to an old assembly version of nhibernate?